# Is multivariate normality assumption found in the estimation process for Path Analysis?

Tags: distributions, structural-equation-modeling

I have read that in path analysis that assumptions are similar to assumptions of multiple regression [Streiner,(2005)](https://doi.org/10.1177/070674370505000207) [Columbia Path Analysis](https://www.publichealth.columbia.edu/research/population-health-methods/path-analysis) 
Particularly around normality of only the dependent/endogenous variables.

I feel conflicted if the normality assumption only applies to the endogenous variables when considering how maximum likelihood estimate is derived. The following equation from Wang, J., & Wang, X. (2019) Eq 1.9. Which comes from Hayduk (1987) This is derived from assuming a multivariate normal population. Which includes the $p$ endogenous and $q$ exogenous variables.
$$
F_{ML}(\theta) = \text{ln}|\hat{\Sigma}| + tr(S\hat{\Sigma}^{-1}) - \text{ln}|S| - (p + q)
$$

As far as I am aware it is this equation that gets maximized for both path analysis and SEM when using maximum likihood. How would the assumption not be multivariate normality for all the variables involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Preamble**

As you **correctly** point out, the maximum likelihood (ML) fit function:

$F_{ML} =$ ln$|\Sigma|+$tr$(\Sigma^{-1}$**S**)-ln|**S**| - $(p+q)$

where $p$ is the number of endogenous variables, $q$ is the number of exogenous variables, $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix matrix implied by the model, and $S$ is the $(p+q)*(p+q)$ sample covariance matrix, assumes multivariate normality (MVN).

This is also the case for the generalized least squares (GLS) fit function:

$F_{GLS}$ = tr$[\Sigma$-**S**)**S**$^{-1}]^2$

which, under the assumption that the observed data **y**$^T$ = $(y_1,y_2,...,y_{p+q})$ follows a MVN distribution, has the same asymptotic properties as ML (Jöreskog & Goldberger, 1972).

**Answer**

Now to your question:

> As far as I am aware it is this equation that gets maximized for both path analysis and SEM. How would the assumption not be multivariate normality for all the variables involved?

The simple answer to your question is that not all SEM fit functions require the assumption of MVN that ML does. For example, unweighted least squares (ULS):

$F_{ULS} = $tr$($**S**$-\Sigma)^2$

and weighted least squares (WLS):

$F_{WLS}$ = (**s**-$\sigma$)$^T$$W^{-1}$(**s**-$\sigma$)

where, **s** = vector(**S**), $\sigma$ = vector($\Sigma$), and $W$ is the weight matrix, both **do not** require one to assume MVN. My guess is that you came across a recourse discussing SEM for categorical data (e.g., Likert scale data) which commonly use ULS or a form of WLS (e.g., diagonally weighted least squares, or DWLS).

Finally, regarding your comment:

> I am interested how some sources only talk about the assumption applying normality to the dependent variables which I don't think is the case when using ML.

The assumption of MVN applies equally to both endogenous and exogenous variables. I am not sure why the MVN assumption is discussed more often, though one reason could be that oftentimes SEM models contain more endogenous variables than exogenous variables, making it a more salient topic. Another is that many SEMs only contain endogenous variables (i.e., [factor analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_analysis) models).

**References**

Jöreskog, K. G., & Goldberger, A. S. (1972). Factor analysis by generalized least squares. Psychometrika, 37(3), 243-260.

Comment: Hi Preston, thank you for the answer. I suppose if we to be exact how we fit the model determines the assumptions we make. Simply using SEM or Path analysis is not enough to imply what assumptions we have when it comes to normality.

Comment: Glad it helped! Regarding testing the assumption of multivariate normality, it is rarely done in practice. Instead, researchers tend to try to be robust to the assumption of normality.

Comment: I reworded my question a bit. I am interested how some sources only talk about the assumption applying normality to the dependent variables which I don't think is the case when using ML.

Comment: @Vefeagins I just edited my response. Does that help?